# На сервере появляется ошибка Uncaught PHPExcel_Writer_Exception: Could not close zip file

Tags: php, ubuntu, сервер, phpexcel

Всем привет.
Ребята, помогите, пожалуйста.
В PHPStorm всё работает отлично, но как только перенёс на сервер - появилась ошибка -

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PHPExcel_Writer_Exception: Could not close zip file simple.xlsx. 
in /var/www/lilya/main/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:389 Stack trace: #0 
/var/www/lilya/main/report.php(247): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('simple.xlsx') 
#1 /var/www/lilya/main/Underwriting.php(2): include('/var/www/lilya/...') 
#2 /var/www/lilya/main/index.php(2): include('/var/www/lilya/...') 
#3 {main} thrown in 
/var/www/lilya/main/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 389
```

Облазил весь интернет, так и не вышло найти решение самостоятельно.
Пробовал давать права на папку, вроде бы всё стоит.
Помогите, пожалуйста. Если необходима дополнительная информация - готов оперативно скинуть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось решить вопрос путём проверки всех необходимых связей.
Изначально в php.ini не прописан open_basedir для сохранения временного файла.
Необходимо его добавить.
Переходим в /etc/php/php7.2(пусть указан примерно, у меня так) дальше в php.ini находим open_basedir и добавляем путь. 
Перезапускаем apache и всё заработало. 
Надеюсь кому-то поможет.